# Can't access android file from terminal

Tags: mount, android, mtp

I can copy files to and from android with nautilus. When I drag a folder in my terminal, it says no such file or directory.

```
$ ls mtp://Xiaomi_SDM636-MTP__SN%3A88E7513B_4d59210/Internal%20shared%20storage/Android/data                                            
ls: cannot access 'mtp://Xiaomi_SDM636-MTP__SN%3A88E7513B_4d59210/Internal%20shared%20storage/Android/data': No such file or directory
```

But I can view the folder with nautilus, as below.

[image: Nautilus]

I've checked `/run/user/1000/gvfs` directory and there is nothing. `lsusb` detects the phone correctly.

Where is it mounted? How can I access it from terminal? I usually do copy pasting large files with `cp` as it is reliable. Nautilus often doesn't work, or fails.

It worked before, stopped after I made some change in my system, like:

1. Uninstalled `gnome-core` and `gnome-shell` (with associated packages)
2. Ran `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Currently I'm in i3 window manager, XFCE DE is also installed.

Comment: If you run `mount`, are there any hints there as to where it's getting mounted?

Comment: No. I ran the command before and after mounting my phone with nautilus, there is no difference in the output of the command. I checked with `diff`.